# Angular 2 and TypeScript. How to compile HTML templates?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, tsc

So I have files `*.ts` and it is easy to understand how to compile into `*.js` using tsc. But a question is how to compile HTML templates which I use in `*.ts` files?

For example, this code appears after it is compiled and launched in HTML file:

```
<script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.14.0.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? or systemjs? or another bundler?

Comment: So, I am just trying to understand the whole example from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Ok, so to be clear - are you trying to import HTML into your component's template?  or are you trying to deploy the main index.html as part of your build process?

Comment: @Dmitry see if this helps http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/

Comment: @Prasad Honrao thank you, I will look at.

Comment: @Delosdos yes, it is the main index.html

Comment: May be I am wrong, I also tried to use Gulp I absolutely do not understand how to compile HTML. Perhaps I do not need to compile HTML files,  do I? But what is it, what created these strings in index.html?

Comment: So firstly, you transpile the TypeScript TS files, which generates JavaScript.    After transpiling your TS you will probably want to bundle all the JS files together and optimize them (minimize, tree-shake, etc, etc) using a tool like webpack/browserify/jspm/etc.  All this does is pull all your js files into a single (or multiple chunks of) JavaScript files.  Then reference the JavaScript file(s) in your HTML, and it's ready to go.  You don't actually transpile the index html itself (though, you can, but that's another story).

Comment: The HTML in your components is different. You can just write HTML inline as as string inside your template, but if you use HTML files you will need to import the HTML as a string and insert it into your template as part of your build process (see answer below).

Comment: @Delosdos thank you so much! It is very useful information for me

Answer (score 1):

You will need some sort of build system to import HTML before compiling your TS.  One way is to use tools like webpack or systemjs to achieve this.

**If you're using Webpack**

You can use `raw-loader` to import HTML files as a string and inline them into your component's template.

Here's an example Webpack config (:

```
module: {
    loaders: [ 
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        include: /src/,
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
      }
    ]
}
```

Then, in your template you can use:

```
template: require('./template.name.html')
```

You can read more about raw-loader here:  https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader

After the loader runs it will import the html and your template will end up inline inside the TS when it is transpiled.  e.g. `template: '<div>your imported html</div>`

**If you're using SystemJs**

You can use the text plugin.  Add it to your config using:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    text: 'path/to/text.js'
  }
});
```

Then import and inline your HTML into your component's template using:

```
template: require('./template.html!text');
```

You can read a bit more about the text plugin here:
https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text

Comment: Or use '`angular2-template-loader` which processes your angular 2 typescript files and does the require for you...

Comment: Yup, though do you know that all `angular2-template-loader` does is swap a `templateUrl` tag for a `template` tag and then inserts a require?  so the end result is the same as my example above.  I removed it in my own project, because it's quite inefficient at parsing lots of templates looking for templateUrl strings and I'm OCD about build times